# Sending Opencv images fromAndroid to PC over TCP

Tags: java, android, c++, opencv, tcp

I'm working on a Android app that grabs a image and sends it to a PC client for display, both the Android app and PC application use Opencv. The image that i want to send over is a color image (grabbed in the rbga format).

First i grab a image in the java app using:

```
InputImage = inputFrame.rgba();
```

Next i am using the Mat image variabele and convert the input image to a byte array using the following native (using JNI) function:

```
    JNIEXPORT jbyteArray JNICALL Java_com_example_communicationmoduleTCPIP_communicationmoduleTCPIP_ConvertImageToByteArray(
        JNIEnv* Env, jobject,
        jlong addrInputImage){

    Mat& OutputImg = *(Mat*) addrInputImage;
    jbyteArray Array;

    //__android_log_write(ANDROID_LOG_ERROR, "Tag", "==== 1 ");

    // Init  java byte array
    Array = Env->NewByteArray(1536000);

    //__android_log_write(ANDROID_LOG_ERROR, "Tag", "==== 2 ");

    // Set byte array region with the size of the SendData CommStruct.
    // Now we can send the data back.
    Env->SetByteArrayRegion(Array, 0, 1536000, (jbyte*)OutputImg.data);

    //__android_log_write(ANDROID_LOG_ERROR, "Tag", "==== 3 ");

        return Array;
}
```

Next is end the byte array (containing the image data) over TCP with the following function:

```
    // Send buffer, the method can be used by both client and server objects.
    public void SendByteBuffer(byte[] ByteBuffer){
    
    try {                         
        // Get socket output stream
        OutputStream OutputBuffer = ClientSocket.getOutputStream();
        
        //Write byte data to outputstream
        OutputBuffer.write(ByteBuffer);  
        
    } 
    catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e("TCPIPCommunicator: ", "Client: Failed to send", e);
        e.printStackTrace();
    }  
}
```

On the PC side (in c++) i recieve the buffer with a boost lib recieve function:

```
int CommunicationModuleTCPIPServer::RecieveBuffer(char Buffer[], int Size){

boost::asio::read(ServerSocket, boost::asio::buffer(TempBuffer, 1536000));
//boost::asio::read(ServerSocket, boost::asio::buffer((char*)InputImage, Size));
//cout <<"Temp buffer: " << TempBuffer << endl;


 int ptr=0;
 for (int i = 0;  i < InputImage.rows; i++) {
  for (int j = 0; j < InputImage.cols; j++) {
      InputImage.at<cv::Vec4b>(i,j) = cv::Vec4b(TempBuffer[ptr+ 0],TempBuffer[ptr+1],TempBuffer[ptr+2],TempBuffer[ptr+3]);
   ptr=ptr+3;
   }
  }

return COMMSUCCES;
```

}

And then i display the variable with the imshow function of opencv. The problem is that i don't get a image in the window on the pc side. i'm thinking the conversion is going wrong somewhere but i dont' see where. Does anybody have a idea? All suggestions and feedback are welcome!

## Update

The code that i have so far is as followed:

On the PC server side i run a small program that recieves the image and tries to show it with imshow, it calls the RecieveImageBuffer function. Below the main function.

```
int ImgReciever(){

    cout << "Setting up monitor server with ip: 192.168.2.11:5000" << endl;
    CommunicationModuleTCPIPServer TICM("192.168.2.11", 5000);
    //CommunicationModuleTCPIPServer TICM("192.168.1.103", 5000);

    VisionModule VM;

    TICM.RunServer();

    char ACK[10];

    ACK[0] = '@';

    while(1){
        cout << "Recieving data...." << endl;
        TICM.RecieveImageBuffer(TICM.TempBuffer, 384000);

        cout << "Data recieved, going to display image" << endl;

        imshow("Testwindow", TICM.InputImage);

        Sleep(1000);

        TICM.SendBuffer(ACK, 1);

    }

    return 0;
}
```

The RecieveImageBuffer function (tried to switch the fors of rows and cols but then the program crashes). The read function alwas recieves 34800 bytes in one read. And Tempbuffer is declared as:

```
uchar TempBuffer[384000]

int CommunicationModuleTCPIPServer::RecieveImageBuffer(uchar Buffer[], int Size){

    Mat Temp;
    int bytecount = 0;
    int bytecountTotal = 0;


    while(bytecountTotal < Size){
        bytecount = boost::asio::read(ServerSocket, boost::asio::buffer(Buffer, Size));
        cout << "Recieved chunck size: " << bytecount << endl;
        bytecountTotal = bytecountTotal + bytecount;
        bytecount = 0;

    }

    cout << "Recieved in total: " + bytecountTotal << endl;

     int ptr=0;
        for (int i = 0;  i < InputImage.rows; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < InputImage.cols; j++) {
          //InputImage.at<cv::Vec4b>(i,j) = cv::Vec4b(TempBuffer[ptr+ 0],TempBuffer[ptr+1],TempBuffer[ptr+2],TempBuffer[ptr+3]);
       //ptr=ptr+3;
          ptr++;
          InputImage.at<uchar>(i,j) = TempBuffer[ptr];

       }
      }

     return COMMSUCCES;
}
```

On the Android side i send the image, firs i grab and convert the graycale image, the buffer sizes matches that of the pc buffer.

```
    OutputImage = inputFrame.gray();
long Size = (OutputImage.total() * OutputImage.channels());
      CMTCP.bufferByte = new byte[(int) Size];
            
CMTCP.bufferByte = ConvertMatToByteArray(OutputImage.getNativeObjAddr(), Size);
```

The ConvertMatToByteArray function looks as followed:

```
JNIEXPORT jbyteArray JNICALL Java_com_example_opencv1_MainActivity_ConvertMatToByteArray(
    JNIEnv* Env, jobject, jlong addrInputImage, jlong Size){

Mat& OutputImg = *(Mat*) addrInputImage;
jbyteArray Array;

// Init  java byte array
Array = Env->NewByteArray(Size);


// Set byte array region with the size of the SendData CommStruct.
// Now we can send the data back.
Env->SetByteArrayRegion(Array, 0, Size, (jbyte*)OutputImg.data);


    return Array;
```

}

The TCP client runs i a thread, that sends a image buffer and then recieves a ack for a new send.

The thread function looks as follows:

```
while(true){
        
        
        if(SendFrame){
            //System.out.println("Converting image");
            // Convert Buffer
            //ImgDataSend = ConvertImageToByteArray(InputImage.getNativeObjAddr(), 10, 20, 30);
            //System.out.println("Image converted");
            
            
            // Send new image buffer
            System.out.println("Sending frame data");
            SendByteBuffer(bufferByte);
            SendFrame = false;
            System.out.println("Image data send");
            
            
            // Wait for ACK 
            while(NoAck){
                RecieveBuffer();
                //System.out.println("Recieved: " +RecieveString);
                
                if(RecieveString == "@"){
                    System.out.println("GOT ACK");
                    bufferByte = new byte[384000];
                    NoAck = false;
                    RecieveString = "#";
                }
            }
        }
```

The SendByteBuffer function looks as followd:

```
    // Send buffer, the method can be used by both client and server objects.
public void SendByteBuffer(byte[] ByteBuffer){

    /*
    BufferedWriter out;
    try {
        out = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(ClientSocket.getOutputStream()));
        out.write(bufferByte.toString()); 
        out.flush();
    } catch (IOException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    } 
    
    */

    try {                         
        // Get socket output stream
        OutputStream OutputBuffer = ClientSocket.getOutputStream();
        
        //Write byte data to outputstream
        OutputBuffer.write(bufferByte);  
        //OutputBuffer.flush();
        
    } 
    catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e("TCPIPCommunicator: ", "Client: Failed to send", e);
        e.printStackTrace();
    }  
}
```

I recieve the send and ACK functions messages, but the window on the PC side that displays the image stays gray and does not responde (says that in the title bar)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I presume you've verified that the comms exchange works ok and there are no little/big endian issues between the platforms, ie. send a small bytes string and check its preserved intact on the other side.

Also, check that read returns all the data - you might need to call it until all the data has been received especially for large byte buffers.

inputFrame.rgba() returns a 4 channel image - I think you need ptr=ptr+4;

Comment: Thank you for comment, just after the post i saw the ptr wrong increment. And fixed that, but i still have the samee problem. Other data structs i can send, say a struct with 8 integers, that is no problem. Any other idea?

Comment: Do you get any image at all (eg. all black - sometimes when the alpha channel is set to 0 it looks like there's no image; that's tripped me up before so something just to watch out for) and how did you dimension InputImage on the PC side - presumably you hardcode to known dimensions from the Android image?

Comment: Hi Tim, thanks for your comments again. On the pc side i make an mat variabele and i init it with the with and height, indeed hardcoded. As format value i gave cv_u8c4 and i also tried grayscale with cv_u8c1(after grabbing grayscale image on android and adjusting the buffer ). I don't thing i got the right image. The window also freezes/doesnt responde. I wish i could show yoi the image. Any ideas?

Comment: Nothing specific just things to think maybe try. 1. check the sign of cv::Vec4b values - they may come out with some negative values - maybe cast to char? 2. I'm not sure if cols come before rows in the byte representation of the Mat - you could try swapping the for's to see if that helps. 3. is the width/height divisible by 4? It's been a while since I played with the C++ version of openCV but I think you had to worry about the step size - to account for a few bytes that acted as spacers at the end of a row. That's about all I can think of -HTH

Comment: Hi Tim thanks, the recieve buffer on the PC side is a uchar(unsigned char). Im just try to send a grayscale image now and recieve it on the pc side. the Format is now cv_u8c1(that is correct of grayscale right?) I will update my code tommorrow would you mind to take a look? The resoluition/dimentions are 480x800 this is compatible i think(?)

Comment: Hi - yes cv_u8c1 is right for greyscale - happy to have a look. cols are width btw so I suspect you also need InputImage.at<cv::Vec4b>(j,i)

Comment: Hi Tim, i put my code under update in the post, i tried your suggestion for switching the rows and cols for's but then the PC application creashes. I you would take a look at my current code that would be great!

Comment: I can have a closer look tonight but one thing that does strike me is the Size value you calculate on the android side is the size of the data and possibly not the size of the Mat - the native Mat structure I think will have other header information so will be larger than the calculated value. I think you may need to serialise the entire object or create a simpler structure that just contains the pixel data and transfer that.

Comment: I tried a little test: i made a jni native function and compared and calculated the size there to with OutputImg.total() * OutputImg.elemSize(); And it gave the same result (348000)

Comment: did you do: 
`Mat m = .... (dimension of your Mat);  
printf("size is %d\n", sizeof(m));`

Comment: No i dind't do that, should m.data() * m.elementsize() not give the same result?

Comment: ok - I see you access the data portion of the Mat in ConvertMatToByteArray so you won't have the issue I suggested above with the Mat header. The only other thing I can suggest is to set  InputImage.at<uchar>(i,j) to some fixed value to prove there's no issue there and then inspect the TempBuffer[ptr] content explicitly to see if there is any issue there (eg. try sending a grey image with all values set to same value). btw I've had problem with signage in the past and sometimes had to do an explicit bitwise and to make sure it was absolutely positive: eg.  & 0xFF

Comment: Hi Tim, i fixed the problem, there where two problems, the firse one is that i dind't gave the imshow function time to display the image. Show i used waitKey to wait one ms. The second problem was that i did'nt use de imencode and decode functions. I don't know if i it is possible to just send raw bytes for streaming but i have read that it is better to incode and decode it on a image format like jpeg. What do you think?

Comment: You should be able to send the raw bytes - I think you said you did it for a structure of 8 ints but you do need to know the underlying structure very well and I think the Mat data structure is fiddly. encoding/decoding seems the best way to go and a quick check says it compresses too so that should improve transfer speeds. Glad you got it sorted so good luck with the rest of your project.